# Extended Exception handling

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I have several custom Exception classes. (Diffrent Error Codes / Error Messages)
Some of those lead to termination. This is why i let them propagate to the main.
To print the error code + message.

If I catch the superclass, is there a way without having a long if else list to check which subclass i have cought to get to the overriden method?

Would it be more readable to have several catch statements?

Should I cast them at a lower level to a higher Exception and only catch this exception?

Comment: "without having a long if else list to check which subclass" You could use a visitor (probably)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to handle a `SubclassOfException` in a particular way, use `catch SubclassOfException`.

There's no point in using a chain of `instanceof` checks when this is basically what the exception handling already does.

```
try {
} catch (SubclassOfException e) {
  // Do something specific to SubclassOfException
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Do something for other types.
}
```

is basically the same as:

```
try {
} catch (Exception e) {
  if (e instanceof SubclassOfException) {
    // Do something specific to SubclassOfException.
    // Note that you have to cast explicitly if you want to use
    // subclass-specific properties of SubclassOfException.
  } else {
    // Do something for other types.
  }
}
```

I think it is clear that the first is more readable, and it will be more efficiently executed, since this is how the JVM expects exception handling code to be written.

Another advantage of writing in the first way is that you can't write:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (SubclassOfException e) {
} catch (SubclassOfSubclassOfException e) {
}
```

because the first catch would catch all exceptions to be matched by the second catch, making the second catch redundant. As such, this is a compile-time error, described in [JLS Sec 11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch an exception class E1 and a preceding catch clause of the immediately enclosing try statement can catch E1 or a superclass of E1.

You need to catch the most-specific types first, and the least-specific types after.

On the other hand,

```
if (e instanceof SubclassOfException) {
} else if (e instanceof SubclassOfSubclassOfException) {
}
```

isn't a compile-time error, even though the second branch cannot be executed either; you'd just see all `SubclassOfSubclassOfException`s being handled as if they were mere `SubclassOfException`s.

Comment: so I would need to order the catch blocks with the lowest inheritance first or is there a way to say look at the base level of this instance?

Comment: @gismo I think the edit I was making when you commented addresses this?